# how to resolve error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified when using ffmpeg-python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge video and audio files together using ffmprg but I keep on receiving this error

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Geo\youtubedownloader\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    ffmpeg.concat(video,audio, v=1 , a=1).output("C:/Users/Geo/output_video/mergedretweett.mp4/").run()
  File "C:\Users\Geo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 313, in run
    process = run_async(
  File "C:\Users\Geo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 284, in run_async
    return subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\Geo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Geo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

**Code:**

````
video = ffmpeg.input("C:/Users/Geo/File.mp4")

audio = ffmpeg.input("C:/Users/Geo/File_audio.mp4")


ffmpeg.concat(video,audio, v=1 , a=1).output("C:/Users/Geo/output_video/outputvideo.mp4").run()```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WindowsError you see does not refer to the video file but to the ffmpeg executable itself. The call to subprocess.call has no idea that File.mp4 is a filename you are passing. Windows knows that the first parameter ought to be an executable file and reports back to the interpreter that it can't find it.

Double-check that ffmpeg can be executed in the environment your interpreter is running in. You may either add it to your PATH or specify the full path to ffmpeg.exe.

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting the same error.
Then I checked and found that, `ffmpeg` is needed.
When I installed it from this code:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

(for anaconda), my issue gets resolved.